# How to configure a running Mule service's properties dynamically?

Tags: mule

I would like a recommendation/idea on a method to configure properties for a running Mule service dynamically, i.e. I want the service to pick up the new settings without the need to restart Mule. Typically the kind of properties/settings I would like to change are FTP connector user ID, passwords, service URLs etc.

Any idea would be welcome.

Regards, Ola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the URI endpoint format do dynamically address endpoints. In simple cases you may be able to use the message properties in a TemplateEndpointRouter

Otherwise You need to write a component that composes the URI and sends the message to the dynamic endpoint using the MuleEventContext or MuleClient.

See here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/Outbound+Routers#OutboundRouters-TemplateEndpointRouter

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/Using+the+Mule+Client#UsingtheMuleClient-PerforminganEventRequestCall

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/Mule+Endpoint+URIs

Answer (score 0):

Mule exposes all service configuration via JMX, but I don't see any obvious way to reconfigure the connectors without a restart. They are internally managing pools of connections.

If there is a limited, you can create connectors for each and reconfigure the routes via jmx attributes.

If it is to be fully dynamic you likely need to implement your own service component to manage the ftp connection. Exposing the connection management, configuration, and restarting via JMX should be pretty straight forward.